# Rendering a heterogeneous list of objects in rails that includes arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render, partial

I have a collection of Attachments, Notes, and Array of Attachments. For example

```
@heteroCollection = [Attachment, Note, Note, [Attachment, Attachment, Attachment]]
```

In my view I attempt to render this collection

```
<%= render :partial => @heteroCollection %>
```

but rails chokes saying the array of attachments needs to implement `:to_partial_path`

```
[Attachment, ..., Attachment] is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path
```

If I remove the array the rendering works great calling `_attachment.html.erb` and `_note.html.erb` for the respective records.

Is there a way to implement :to_partial_path on Array without monkey patching? Or is there another better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the class AttachmentArray, extend it from Array and add the to_partial_path method to it. Than push your attachments to a new instance of that class..